# Reading .jks file from web application using FileInputStream

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, web-applications

How do you read a `.jks` file from a rest web application deployed with Tomcat server ? I am using `FileInputStream` to read the file. I am currently having difficulty dealing with the relative paths used to read a file in a web application. I know the file will be under `WEB-INF/classes`. What will be the best way to read the file using `FileInputStream`. I know using `classLoader`. but then it returns the `InputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad practice to use direct file access (`FileInputStream`) for reading resources that are bundled with the application; the reason is that it leads to precisely the sort of problems like you're experiencing. In a managed runtime environment, the developer has very little control over the paths where resources are actually located.

For servlet-based applications (which you are using, as you mentioned that you're using Tomcat), the best way to go about it is to use the context classloader:

`Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`

and load the resource from there, getting an `InputStream`. In other words - you're doing things correctly at the moment. Don't use `FileInputStream`. Unless you have an absolutely good reason for doing so, in which case I'm going to be extremely surprised.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to access files which are not bundled with EAR / WAR is to use java.util.Properties. I am sure that files like jks files are never bundled with EAR , they are in domain folder of the server or server dir ( weblogic , websphere.). Properties file should be placed on file location independent of the server installed directory.

Here is the solution I can think of :

```
1. Initialize a Servlet with init-param in web.xml
2. The init-param can be the absolute file location  
   <param-name>porperies-file</param-name>
   <param-value>/usr/properties/abc.jks</param-value>
3. In the static block of the Servlet , load the properties file / jks 
   file and store it    in parameter
```

This look complex but many frameworks give the option of locating files like ResourceBundle files through Absoulute path. Check the documentation for Spring's FileSystemResourceLoader.

The advantage of such a process is if the "jks" file changes you just need to start the server. In the case where you have the propeties file in EAR , you need to deploy the application and then restart the server. Consider this also , you can have logic to check the freshness of the file. In this case the system need not be re-started at all but you have to put extra bit of logic of synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

if you make a KeyStore(w/o password,and defaultType)

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jskFileName"); 
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(is, null);
```

but FileInputStream is really good if you...

Please note that when you use the cluster servers.

for example

```
/contextPath
    /WEB-INF
    /pathA/
       /sample.jks

ServletContext sc
String path="/pathA/sample.jks";
String realPath = sc.getRealPath(path);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(realPath));
```

Comment: The point here is that the default classloader configuration for Tomcat places `WEB-INF/classes` close to the top of the priority list (See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html). `getResourceAsStream()` is used to locate the file in the classpath. The latter example shows how to load a file that's not within the classpath, including `WEB-INF/classes`. @user1428716 has a good point that it's best to allow the path to be configurable outside of the code.